# NSRunAlertPanel and hyperlink

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, core-foundation, nsrunalertpanel

Is it possible to insert hyperlink into `NSRunAlertPanel` message text, using standard apple tools?

Comment: You should avoid using the `NSRunAlertPanel()` function and use the `NSAlert` object instead.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that this is possible because the message in an `NSAlert` panel is just a string, or in other words just simple text. If it wasn't just a string but for example `NSMutableAttributedString`, that would be possible.

So I suggest you create a custom panel, view or window and your hyperlink in that.